# Flutter retuns error compiling hello world app

Tags: android, windows, flutter

I am trying to run the "hello world" app that is generated when you create a new app. This is error that I keep getting when I try to run it in Visual Studio Code:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:processDebugManifest' (type 'ProcessMultiApkApplicationManifest').
> File 'G:\Projects\flutter\brew_crew4\build\app\intermediates\merged_manifest\debug\out\AndroidManifest.xml' specified for property 'mainMergedManifest' does not exist.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 39s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I'm using JDK 1.8.291 and Gradle 7.0

I'm running the latest verion of Flutter as of the date of this post (2.2.3). Here is the output of "flutter doctor". There are no issues whatosever! On my Mac that has the saem version of Gradle and JDK, I can run flutter apps without problems!

```
    • Flutter version 2.2.3 at d:\WebProjects\utils\flutter
    • Framework revision f4abaa0735 (7 days ago), 2021-07-01 12:46:11 -0700
    • Engine revision 241c87ad80
    • Dart version 2.13.4

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at D:\Android\Sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = D:\Android\Sdk
    • Java binary at: D:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6842174)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[✓] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2019 16.9.4)
    • Visual Studio at g:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community
    • Visual Studio Community 2019 version 16.9.31205.134
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.19041.0

[✓] Android Studio
    • Android Studio at D:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • android-studio-dir = D:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6842174)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.57.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.24.0

[✓] Connected device (4 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 64 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x64    • Android 10 (API 29) (emulator)
    • Windows (desktop)                     • windows       • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version
      10.0.19043.1052]
    • Chrome (web)                          • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 91.0.4472.124
    • Edge (web)                            • edge          • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 91.0.864.64

• No issues found!
```

I have tried reinstalling the JDK and Android Studio twice.

UPDATE: This is the contents of my build.gradle file:

```
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Show us the file build.gradle.

Comment: does create another new project persist the same problem?

Comment: @eishon Yes the same error turns up if create another new project

Comment: I have updated my question to include the build.gradle contents @filipe-piletti-plucenio

Comment: can you share the error message with stack trace options? I don't think this is the problem with gradle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED: Apparently, starting from Gradle 6.5, it stopped working well on drives formatted as exFAT. If you must have your project on an exFAT partitioned drive, downgrade the gradle plugin in build.gradle to 4.0.2:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
```

and downgrade the gradle version in gradle.properties to 6.4.1:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.4.1-all.zip
```